# How to set username using createSignInIntentBuilder() with AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, authorization

I'm trying to make authorization for my app with phone number and username using **createSignInIntentBuilder()**

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setAvailableProviders(
            Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().alsoAddUsername().build()))
        .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
        .build(),
    SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
);
```

what should I use instead of **.alsoAddUsername()** ?

Comment: May I ask: Why do you want to use Phone Number and Username? Will a user be allowed to have a single phone number and multiple usernames? Or maybe one username for multiple phones?

Comment: Phone number will be used for authorization, and username will be used to display for other users. So it will be nickname that can be changed anytime.

Comment: Last question: Does this nickname need to be unique? Can 2 users have the same nickname?

Comment: Users can have same nickname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone Auth doesn't provide a way to prompt for a nickname on Sign in. But you can do that after the user signs in.

Sign the user in normally:

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setAvailableProviders(
            Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()))
        .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
        .build(),
    SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
);
```

Then in your `onActivityResult` method, prompt the user for the desired nickname (you'll most certainly use an [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) for this).

And finally, tell Firebase to use that name:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName(nickname)
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User nickname is set!");
                }
            }
        });
```

You can then access the current user's phone number and display name (in any Activity) with the following code:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String phone = user.getPhoneNumber();
String nickname = user.getDisplayName();
```